# Setting a result from task in an azure pipeline variable

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have setup a in my azure pipeline which create a Redis cache instance through Azure CLI.
There is another task which runs afterwards that pick set the values in my application config file from a pipeline variable named "CacheConnectionKey".

I have to set the variable value manually in the pipeline. I want to automate this process by adding a new task in between both described above. The new task should get PrimaryKey from Redis cache instance and set the value in the pipeline variable (i.e. CacheConnectionKey).

There is a command I have tried in the power shell which is giving me the access keys:

```
Get-AzRedisCacheKey -ResourceGroupName "MyResourceGroup" -Name "MyCacheKey"
PrimaryKey        : pJ+jruGKPHDKsEC8kmoybobH3TZx2njBR3ipEsquZFo=
SecondaryKey      : sJ+jruGKPHDKsEC8kmoybobH3TZx2njBR3ipEsquZFo=
```

Now I want to set PrimaryKey resulting from this command to be set in the pipeline variable CacheConnectionKey so that the next process could use the value properly.

Comment: Do you want to use this in the same run? the same job? Or in another run of the pipeline?

Comment: I want to use it in the same run of the pipeline, but in a different job.

Answer (score 1):

The "process" referred in the question could be anything like a run/job/stage/pipeline I suppose. Regardless, in YAML pipelines, you can set variables at the root, stage, and job level. You can also use a [variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops) to make variables available across multiple pipelines. Some tasks define output variables, which you can consume in **downstream steps, jobs, and stages**.

In YAML, you can access variables across jobs and stages by using [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies). By default, each stage in a pipeline depends on the one just before it in the YAML file. So if you need to refer to a stage that isn't immediately prior to the current one, you can override this automatic default by adding a `dependsOn` section to the stage.

For example, let's assume you have a task called `MyTask`, which sets an output variable called `MyVar`.

To use outputs in the same job:

```
steps:
- task: MyTask@1  # this step generates the output variable
  name: ProduceVar  # because we're going to depend on it, we need to name the step
- script: echo $(ProduceVar.MyVar) # this step uses the output variable
```

To use outputs in a different job:

```
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  # assume that MyTask generates an output variable called "MyVar"
  - task: MyTask@1
    name: ProduceVar  # because we're going to depend on it, we need to name the step
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    # map the output variable from A into this job
    varFromA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['ProduceVar.MyVar'] ]
  steps:
  - script: echo $(varFromA) # this step uses the mapped-in variable
```

For more details on the syntax and examples, check the following articles:

- [Use output variables from tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-output-variables-from-tasks)
- [Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies)

Comment: how does MyTask work.. I have this exact code example yaml stuff and getting nothing on echo job B